# How can I create a column or summary table that lists the available years of data that a value has?

Tags: r, dplyr, summarize

So I have the following data that looks like this (its a sample, with hundreds of rows over a span of ~15 years). I would like to create a column (or summary table) that displays the years of available data for each location.

```
Year, Place
2000, 'Adak'
2000, 'Kodiak'
2000, 'Saltsdale'
2001, 'Adak'
2001, 'Saltsdale'
2001, 'Tawney'
2002, 'Adak'
2002, 'Kodiak'
2002, 'Tawney'
```

I would really like it to look like this if possible:

```
Place, Years_Available 
'Adak', 2000/2002
'Kodiak', 2000/2002
'Saltsdale', 2000/2001
'Tawney', 2001/2002
```

I have used summarize_all but its giving me a weird output where the Years_Available column is just repeating the first year 15 times.

```
b1 <- b %>% 
    group_by(Place) %>%
    mutate(years = toString(Year)) %>%
    group_by(Place,years) %>%
    summarize_all(funs(sum(!is.na(.))))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `range`

```
df1 %>%
   group_by(Place) %>% 
   summarise(Year = toString(range(Year)))
```

Comment: When I apply this to larger data set, I get the same range (first year to the last year) for every place which is inaccurate unfortunately.

Comment: @JulietR  Could you check if your `Year` column is string or numeric?